# Stored Prodcedure SQL Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

If **CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS** is  either **null** or **Zero**,Then it should select ***COMP_DUE_DAYS FROM COMP***.

```
SELECT CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS,
                CASE
                WHEN CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS IS NULL THEN (SELECT COMP_DUE_DAYS FROM COMP)
                END as xyz
                FROM vwCLNT
                WHERE CLNT_COMP_ID=1
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting database tags. Please re-tag with the actual database platform you are using. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Also, sample data and expected results would be helpful. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your questions with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: What's the common column between COMP and vwCLNT tables ..?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server. So, why can't you join the `vwCLNT` and `COMP` and just use `ISNULL(CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS,COMP_DUE_DAYS)` . If `CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS` can have 0, then keep the `CASE` statement, but include the `JOIN`.

Comment: can u describe more

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear.  If you still need help, sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: i am beginner cam u help me please stil not solve

Comment: The subqeury obviously returns more than one value. We can't know which value you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as mentioned in the comments) is that your subquery can return more than 1 row. This means that the results would not be in a table format but more like a treeview hierarchy where each row has multiple rows attached to it and that does not work in SQL.

Based on the limited details in your question this should work assuming CLNT_COMP_ID is a key in both tables:

```
SELECT a.CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS
       , CASE
           WHEN ISNULL(a.CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS, 0) = 0 THEN b.COMP_DUE_DAYS
       ELSE a.CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS
       END AS xyz
FROM   vwCLNT a
       LEFT JOIN COMP b ON a.CLNT_COMP_ID = b.CLNT_COMP_ID
WHERE  a.CLNT_COMP_ID = 1;
```

Or this which is closer to your original query where you give the subquery an id from each row in the main query:

```
SELECT    CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS
        , CASE
              WHEN CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS IS NULL THEN
                (
                    SELECT COMP_DUE_DAYS
                    FROM    COMP b
                    WHERE  a.CLNT_COMP_ID = b.CLNT_COMP_ID
                )
          END AS xyz
FROM vwCLNT a
WHERE CLNT_COMP_ID = 1;
```

If it does not work then please provide more details such as table structure and data examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add `top 1` to the sub query to limit the results to one row

You may needs to add a `where` clause or `order` condition as well to ensure the single row that is returned is the correct one.

```
SELECT CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS,
                CASE
                WHEN CLNT_PAYMENT_DAYS IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP 1 COMP_DUE_DAYS FROM COMP)
                END as xyz
                FROM vwCLNT
                WHERE CLNT_COMP_ID=1
```